# Pagination on a song request page

Tags: php, foreach, pagination

I am trying to get pagination on a page for song requests. I found a Liquidsoap song request PHP page that works currently: http://quinnebert.net/my-software/liquidsoap-requester/ but it doesn't have pagination. It just lists all the songs. And the author seems to be coding all of this in a weird way, so I am not sure what to make of it.

Here is the request page: http://req.bronydom.net/

The requests work fine and everything, it's just the pagination that I want to get working.

This is the code for displaying the songs (in a `foreach` loop and stuff):

```
$list = file($mReadIn,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  if ( $list ) {
    foreach ($list as $file) {
      $song = req_meta($file);
      // A few hacks to escape special characters properly
      // for maintaining HTML4 compliance:
      $file = str_replace('&','&amp;',$file);
      $had = FALSE;
      if ($gus == '')

        echo '<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" align="center"><div id="songContainer"><form action="'.basename(__FILE__).'?act=req&amp;que='.urlencode($file).'" method=POST><!--<b>File: '.str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',basename($file)).'</b><br>-->'.$song.'&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="hoverbutton" name="request" value="Request This Song"></form></div></td></tr>'."\n";
if ($gus != '' && strstr(stl($file),stl($gus))) {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" align="center"><div id="songContainer"><form action="'.basename(__FILE__).'?act=req&amp;que='.urlencode($file).'" method=POST><!--<b>File: '.str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',basename($file)).'</b><br>-->'.$song.'&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="hoverbutton" name="request" value="Request This Song"></form></div></td></tr>'."\n"; 
        $had = TRUE;
      }
      if ($had != TRUE && $gus != '' && strstr(stl($song),stl($gus)))
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2" valign="top" align="center"><div id="songContainer"><form action="'.basename(__FILE__).'?act=req&amp;que='.urlencode($file).'" method=POST><!--<b>File: '.str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',basename($file)).'</b><br>-->'.$song.'&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="hoverbutton" name="request" value="Request This Song"></form></div></td></tr>'."\n";
    }
  } else {
    echo("<strong>PROBLEM:</strong><br><br>Unable to read the playlist file at &quot;$mReadIn&quot;!");
  }
```

Here's a brief picture of what I want it to look like (with really bad handwriting):

[image: What I want it to look like]

(Also when you are on page 2+, it should show a previous button)

Comment: Pagination from a list pulled from the filesystem probably won't work well because the OS might return the files in different order different times. You need a db with a query that orders them by something specific (like an autoincrement id). Then just make your back and forward links specify an index you pass to the query, or something like that. Its so simple I'm surprised its asked like 100 times a day.

Comment: Or simple sort the file list. If it doesn't change so frequently it won't be a problem to use the filelist.

Comment: What's with the downvote on my question? I think I made it clear to what I was asking and what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a $start variable in your url. Then you can print it before the loop:

```
if ( $list ) {
    //Check for $start value
    if (!isset($start) || ($start < 0)) { $start = 0; }
    if ($start > sizeof($list)) { $start = sizeof($list); }
    print($start.' - '.($start+50).' / '.sizeof($list).'<br>');
```

Then replace the foreach loop with a simple for loop:

```
for ($i = $start; $i < $start + 50; $i++) {
    $file = $list[$i]; //To be compatible
```

Then under the list, you can add the pagination:

```
if ($start > 0) {    
    print('<a href="..&start='.($start-50).'">Prev</a>');
}
if ($start < sizeof($list)-50) {
    print('<a href="..&start='.($start+50).'">Next</a>');
}
```

If you need a more complex one, feel free to comment.

Greetings

Comment: Of course, it's a good idea to put the number of items on a page to a variable (like $items_per_page = 50), this way you can modify it only one place.